# Need to call PHP twice before getting correct results

Tags: php, jquery

I am using PHP to echo the last x lines from a file, but it is sending back old data. If I call the PHP directly, then refresh, it shows the correct data.
However, from the HTML page that calls the PHP (using jQuery), it will then only load that data that was last shown until I call the PHP directly and refresh again.

I had used this same code on another server with no issues whatsoever. It just seems to be on this new server that the problem is.

This is the PHP snippet

```
$file = file("thisisarealpath/server_chat.log") or die("No Server Chat Found");
if (count($file) > $MAX_SERVER_LINES) {
    for ($i = count($file) - $MAX_SERVER_LINES;$i < count($file); $i++) {
        echo "<span id=\"serverMessage\">" . $file[$i] . "</span><br/>";
    }
} else {
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($file); $i++) {
        echo "<span id=\"serverMessage\">" . $file[$i] . "</span><br/>";
    }
}
```

This is the jQuery calling it

```
setInterval(function() {
        if (window.refresh) {
            $("#serverLog").load("GetLogs.php?logType=server&pass=" + window.pass);
        }
}, 3000);
```

Refreshing the HTML page does not resolve the issue. The only "fix" I have found is hitting the PHP directly, then refreshing.

Comment: Do you have any logs or anything else to go on?

Comment: between if your log file will get bigger , you cant load all content into an array with file() take a look examples of [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the new server's configuration is allowing it to cache requests that were not previously cached. Check your requests' status codes; they may be showing `304 Not modified`. A common solution that may be relevant is to tack on a superfluous parameter that's always set to the current time, intended to force the server to respond with the current resource, bypassing caching.

Comment: I was thinking it would be caching, I just wasn't sure how to get past it. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: You bet. Happy to help a fellow midwesterner. ;)